# Show us detailed close vote count for migrations / duplicates, after voting

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close, migration, duplicate-questions

When you open the close dialog *after having voted yourself*, you get the same dialog as normal, but without the radio buttons. You can see the vote counts on the different categories. However, you can't click further on a categorie, so you can't see:

- How much is voted on particular possible duplicates
- How much is voted for migration paths / no migration

Can it be made that you can click further so that you can see these vote counts as well? Another option is, as [Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard) says, to add close votes to the timeline. The dialog wouldn't have to be changed with that idea.

[image]

There might be little user scripts hacks or so, but I'd say it would be nice to have this as a site feature.

Comment: One other way without changing the close dialog is adding close votes to the question timeline. [Example of question with some pending close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/987982/timeline). Of course visible only for 3K+ users.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd nice suggestion, I edited it in.

Comment: @Manishearth I upvoted your answer and will use it, but wanted to make clear that I want something more than that. Thanks a lot for the JS, I'm going to use it (a lot)!

Comment: @CamilStaps: Yeah, I'm saying that it's always implied that you still want the feature :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, when I want to know the close vote distribution on a site where I don't have the rep to I use this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:$.get('/posts/popup/close/'+document.location.href.split('/')[4],function(data){$d=$(data);$d.find('.bounty-indicator-tab').each(function(){console.log($(this).parent().find('.action-name').html()+": "+$(this).html())})})
```

This logs the close vote counts onto the JS console (Ctrl-Shift-J on Chrome), *including the submenu counts*. And it ought to work even after a close vote has been cast by you.

Note: The "null" field is the amount of close votes you have left for the day.