# Provide link to see off-topic close reason after vote

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, vote-to-close

After voting to close as **off-topic**, I'm unable to see which option I chose by clicking on the `close` button again:

[image: no link]

There is no link to click through and see the counts associated with each off-topic close reason. Can we add one? Something like:

[image: example interface]

<sub>Yes, I realise the numbers don't add up. My Paint-fu isn't great.</sub>

Comment: Old issue, been suggested before and curiously ignored: [Seeing close-vote details if I've already voted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101571/seeing-close-vote-details-if-ive-already-voted) and [Show us detailed close vote count for migrations / duplicates, after voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178211)

Comment: This is more important on StackOverflow since some "off-topic" reasons are actually not quite obvious (e.g. minimal understanding)

Comment: I'm asking just for the functionality suggested above (e.g. off-topic), whereas both suggested duplicates are asking for much wider functionality (counts per duplicate, migration site choices etc.) Shouldn't this be re-opened?